# Reset Spinning Progress Indicator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, appkit, nsprogressindicator

A simple question here for many of you. I have an indeterminate `NSProgressIndicator` which I start and stop many times in my code. Does it reset when you call restart it, or do you have to manually do that? If you do have to do it manually, how would I go about doing it?

Many thanks,
jrtc27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of resetting an *indeterminate* spinner... It's indeterminate. Which aspect of the spinner do you want to reset???

Comment: I want to reset the animation (so the darkest rectangle is at the top)

Comment: Stopping the animation automatically does that. But it's not documented anywhere.